# How to hand on libjpeg library the path where libtool is statically installed?

Tags: image, makefile, configure, libtool, libjpeg

I want to install statically libjpeg (https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg/files/libjpeg/6b/jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz/download). I also successfully installed the dependencies:

m4-1.4.9 for libtool

```
./configure --enable-static --prefix=/home/$USER/Desktop/KIS/libs/jpeg-6b
```

libtoolfor libjpeg

```
./configure --enable-static --prefix=path_to_libs/libs/libtool-2.4.6 M4=path_to_libs/libs/m4-1.4.9/bin/m4
make install
```

libjpeg

```
./configure --enable-static --prefix=path_to_libs/libs/jpeg-6b

checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for function prototypes... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for type unsigned char... yes
checking for type unsigned short... yes
checking for type void... yes
checking for working const... yes
checking for inline... __inline__
checking for broken incomplete types... ok
checking for short external names... ok
checking to see if char is signed... yes
checking to see if right shift is signed... yes
checking to see if fopen accepts b spec... yes
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-    linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking libjpeg version number... 62
creating ./config.status
creating Makefile
creating jconfig.h
jconfig.h is unchanged
```

And make:

```
make LIBTOOL=../libtool-2.4.6/libtool
make install LIBTOOL=../libtool-2.4.6/libtool
./libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c cjpeg path_to_libs/libs/jpeg-6b/bin/cjpeg
libtool: warning: 'libjpeg.la' has not been installed in 'path_to_libs/libs/jpeg-6b/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/cjpeg path_to_libs/libs/jpeg-6b/bin/cjpeg
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file 'path_to_libs/libs/jpeg-6b/bin/cjpeg': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:194: install] Error 1
```

And it fails

Hereby the generated makefile:

```
# Generated automatically from makefile.cfg by configure.
# Makefile for Independent JPEG Group's software

# makefile.cfg is edited by configure to produce a custom Makefile.

# Read installation instructions before saying "make" !!

# For compiling with source and object files in different directories.
srcdir = .

# Where to install the programs and man pages.
prefix = /home/ubuntu/Desktop/KIS/libs/jpeg-6b
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
bindir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
libdir = $(exec_prefix)/lib
includedir = $(prefix)/include
binprefix =
manprefix =
manext = 1
mandir = $(prefix)/man/man$(manext)

# The name of your C compiler:
CC= gcc

# You may need to adjust these cc options:
CFLAGS= -O2  -I$(srcdir)
# Generally, we recommend defining any configuration symbols in jconfig.h,
# NOT via -D switches here.
# However, any special defines for ansi2knr.c may be included here:
ANSI2KNRFLAGS= 

# Link-time cc options:
LDFLAGS= 

# To link any special libraries, add the necessary -l commands here.
LDLIBS= 

# If using GNU libtool, LIBTOOL references it; if not, LIBTOOL is empty.
LIBTOOL = ./libtool
# $(O) expands to "lo" if using libtool, plain "o" if not.
# Similarly, $(A) expands to "la" or "a".
O = lo
A = la

# Library version ID; libtool uses this for the shared library version number.
# Note: we suggest this match the macro of the same name in jpeglib.h.
JPEG_LIB_VERSION = 62

# Put here the object file name for the correct system-dependent memory
# manager file.  For Unix this is usually jmemnobs.o, but you may want
# to use jmemansi.o or jmemname.o if you have limited swap space.
SYSDEPMEM= jmemnobs.$(O)

# miscellaneous OS-dependent stuff
SHELL= /bin/sh
# linker
LN= $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC)
# file deletion command
RM= rm -f
# directory creation command
MKDIR= mkdir
# library (.a) file creation command
AR= ar rc
# second step in .a creation (use "touch" if not needed)
AR2= ranlib
# installation program
INSTALL= /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM= $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_LIB= $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_DATA= ${INSTALL} -m 644

# End of configurable options.


# source files: JPEG library proper
LIBSOURCES= jcapimin.c jcapistd.c jccoefct.c jccolor.c jcdctmgr.c jchuff.c \
        jcinit.c jcmainct.c jcmarker.c jcmaster.c jcomapi.c jcparam.c \
        jcphuff.c jcprepct.c jcsample.c jctrans.c jdapimin.c jdapistd.c \
        jdatadst.c jdatasrc.c jdcoefct.c jdcolor.c jddctmgr.c jdhuff.c \
        jdinput.c jdmainct.c jdmarker.c jdmaster.c jdmerge.c jdphuff.c \
        jdpostct.c jdsample.c jdtrans.c jerror.c jfdctflt.c jfdctfst.c \
        jfdctint.c jidctflt.c jidctfst.c jidctint.c jidctred.c jquant1.c \
        jquant2.c jutils.c jmemmgr.c
# memmgr back ends: compile only one of these into a working library
SYSDEPSOURCES= jmemansi.c jmemname.c jmemnobs.c jmemdos.c jmemmac.c
# source files: cjpeg/djpeg/jpegtran applications, also rdjpgcom/wrjpgcom
APPSOURCES= cjpeg.c djpeg.c jpegtran.c rdjpgcom.c wrjpgcom.c cdjpeg.c \
        rdcolmap.c rdswitch.c transupp.c rdppm.c wrppm.c rdgif.c wrgif.c \
        rdtarga.c wrtarga.c rdbmp.c wrbmp.c rdrle.c wrrle.c
SOURCES= $(LIBSOURCES) $(SYSDEPSOURCES) $(APPSOURCES)
# files included by source files
INCLUDES= jchuff.h jdhuff.h jdct.h jerror.h jinclude.h jmemsys.h jmorecfg.h \
        jpegint.h jpeglib.h jversion.h cdjpeg.h cderror.h transupp.h
# documentation, test, and support files
DOCS= README install.doc usage.doc cjpeg.1 djpeg.1 jpegtran.1 rdjpgcom.1 \
        wrjpgcom.1 wizard.doc example.c libjpeg.doc structure.doc \
        coderules.doc filelist.doc change.log
MKFILES= configure makefile.cfg makefile.ansi makefile.unix makefile.bcc \
        makefile.mc6 makefile.dj makefile.wat makefile.vc makelib.ds \
        makeapps.ds makeproj.mac makcjpeg.st makdjpeg.st makljpeg.st \
        maktjpeg.st makefile.manx makefile.sas makefile.mms makefile.vms \
        makvms.opt
CONFIGFILES= jconfig.cfg jconfig.bcc jconfig.mc6 jconfig.dj jconfig.wat \
        jconfig.vc jconfig.mac jconfig.st jconfig.manx jconfig.sas \
        jconfig.vms
CONFIGUREFILES= config.guess config.sub install-sh ltconfig ltmain.sh
OTHERFILES= jconfig.doc ckconfig.c ansi2knr.c ansi2knr.1 jmemdosa.asm
TESTFILES= testorig.jpg testimg.ppm testimg.bmp testimg.jpg testprog.jpg \
        testimgp.jpg
DISTFILES= $(DOCS) $(MKFILES) $(CONFIGFILES) $(SOURCES) $(INCLUDES) \
        $(CONFIGUREFILES) $(OTHERFILES) $(TESTFILES)
# library object files common to compression and decompression
COMOBJECTS= jcomapi.$(O) jutils.$(O) jerror.$(O) jmemmgr.$(O) $(SYSDEPMEM)
# compression library object files
CLIBOBJECTS= jcapimin.$(O) jcapistd.$(O) jctrans.$(O) jcparam.$(O) \
        jdatadst.$(O) jcinit.$(O) jcmaster.$(O) jcmarker.$(O) jcmainct.$(O) \
        jcprepct.$(O) jccoefct.$(O) jccolor.$(O) jcsample.$(O) jchuff.$(O) \
        jcphuff.$(O) jcdctmgr.$(O) jfdctfst.$(O) jfdctflt.$(O) \
        jfdctint.$(O)
# decompression library object files
DLIBOBJECTS= jdapimin.$(O) jdapistd.$(O) jdtrans.$(O) jdatasrc.$(O) \
        jdmaster.$(O) jdinput.$(O) jdmarker.$(O) jdhuff.$(O) jdphuff.$(O) \
        jdmainct.$(O) jdcoefct.$(O) jdpostct.$(O) jddctmgr.$(O) \
        jidctfst.$(O) jidctflt.$(O) jidctint.$(O) jidctred.$(O) \
        jdsample.$(O) jdcolor.$(O) jquant1.$(O) jquant2.$(O) jdmerge.$(O)
# These objectfiles are included in libjpeg.a
LIBOBJECTS= $(CLIBOBJECTS) $(DLIBOBJECTS) $(COMOBJECTS)
# object files for sample applications (excluding library files)
COBJECTS= cjpeg.$(O) rdppm.$(O) rdgif.$(O) rdtarga.$(O) rdrle.$(O) \
        rdbmp.$(O) rdswitch.$(O) cdjpeg.$(O)
DOBJECTS= djpeg.$(O) wrppm.$(O) wrgif.$(O) wrtarga.$(O) wrrle.$(O) \
        wrbmp.$(O) rdcolmap.$(O) cdjpeg.$(O)
TROBJECTS= jpegtran.$(O) rdswitch.$(O) cdjpeg.$(O) transupp.$(O)


all:  libjpeg.$(A) cjpeg djpeg jpegtran rdjpgcom wrjpgcom

# Special compilation rules to support ansi2knr and libtool.
.SUFFIXES: .lo .la

# How to compile with libtool.
.c.lo:
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/$*.c

# How to use ansi2knr, when not using libtool.
# .c.o:
#   ./ansi2knr $(srcdir)/$*.c knr/$*.c
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c knr/$*.c
#   $(RM) knr/$*.c

# How to use ansi2knr AND libtool.
# .c.lo:
#   ./ansi2knr $(srcdir)/$*.c knr/$*.c
#   $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c knr/$*.c
#   $(RM) knr/$*.c

ansi2knr: ansi2knr.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ANSI2KNRFLAGS) -o ansi2knr $(srcdir)/ansi2knr.c
    $(MKDIR) knr

# the library:

# without libtool:
libjpeg.a:  $(LIBOBJECTS)
    $(RM) libjpeg.a
    $(AR) libjpeg.a  $(LIBOBJECTS)
    $(AR2) libjpeg.a

# with libtool:
libjpeg.la:  $(LIBOBJECTS)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) -o libjpeg.la $(LIBOBJECTS) \
        -rpath $(libdir) -version-info $(JPEG_LIB_VERSION)

# sample programs:

cjpeg: $(COBJECTS) libjpeg.$(A)
    $(LN) $(LDFLAGS) -o cjpeg $(COBJECTS) libjpeg.$(A) $(LDLIBS)

djpeg: $(DOBJECTS) libjpeg.$(A)
    $(LN) $(LDFLAGS) -o djpeg $(DOBJECTS) libjpeg.$(A) $(LDLIBS)

jpegtran: $(TROBJECTS) libjpeg.$(A)
    $(LN) $(LDFLAGS) -o jpegtran $(TROBJECTS) libjpeg.$(A) $(LDLIBS)

rdjpgcom: rdjpgcom.$(O)
    $(LN) $(LDFLAGS) -o rdjpgcom rdjpgcom.$(O) $(LDLIBS)

wrjpgcom: wrjpgcom.$(O)
    $(LN) $(LDFLAGS) -o wrjpgcom wrjpgcom.$(O) $(LDLIBS)

# Installation rules:

install: cjpeg djpeg jpegtran rdjpgcom wrjpgcom 
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) cjpeg $(bindir)/$(binprefix)cjpeg
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) djpeg $(bindir)/$(binprefix)djpeg
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) jpegtran $(bindir)/$(binprefix)jpegtran
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) rdjpgcom $(bindir)/$(binprefix)rdjpgcom
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) wrjpgcom $(bindir)/$(binprefix)wrjpgcom
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/cjpeg.1 $(mandir)/$(manprefix)cjpeg.$(manext)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/djpeg.1 $(mandir)/$(manprefix)djpeg.$(manext)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/jpegtran.1 $(mandir)/$(manprefix)jpegtran.$(manext)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/rdjpgcom.1 $(mandir)/$(manprefix)rdjpgcom.$(manext)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/wrjpgcom.1 $(mandir)/$(manprefix)wrjpgcom.$(manext)

install-lib: libjpeg.$(A) install-headers
    $(INSTALL_LIB) libjpeg.$(A) $(libdir)/$(binprefix)libjpeg.$(A)

install-headers: jconfig.h
    $(INSTALL_DATA) jconfig.h $(includedir)/jconfig.h
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/jpeglib.h $(includedir)/jpeglib.h
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/jmorecfg.h $(includedir)/jmorecfg.h
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/jerror.h $(includedir)/jerror.h

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.lo libjpeg.a libjpeg.la
    $(RM) cjpeg djpeg jpegtran rdjpgcom wrjpgcom
    $(RM) ansi2knr core testout* config.log config.status
    $(RM) -r knr .libs _libs

distclean: clean
    $(RM) Makefile jconfig.h libtool config.cache

test: cjpeg djpeg jpegtran
    $(RM) testout*
    ./djpeg -dct int -ppm -outfile testout.ppm  $(srcdir)/testorig.jpg
    ./djpeg -dct int -bmp -colors 256 -outfile testout.bmp  $(srcdir)/testorig.jpg
    ./cjpeg -dct int -outfile testout.jpg  $(srcdir)/testimg.ppm
    ./djpeg -dct int -ppm -outfile testoutp.ppm $(srcdir)/testprog.jpg
    ./cjpeg -dct int -progressive -opt -outfile testoutp.jpg $(srcdir)/testimg.ppm
    ./jpegtran -outfile testoutt.jpg $(srcdir)/testprog.jpg
    cmp $(srcdir)/testimg.ppm testout.ppm
    cmp $(srcdir)/testimg.bmp testout.bmp
    cmp $(srcdir)/testimg.jpg testout.jpg
    cmp $(srcdir)/testimg.ppm testoutp.ppm
    cmp $(srcdir)/testimgp.jpg testoutp.jpg
    cmp $(srcdir)/testorig.jpg testoutt.jpg

check: test

# Mistake catcher:

jconfig.h: jconfig.doc
    echo You must prepare a system-dependent jconfig.h file.
    echo Please read the installation directions in install.doc.
    exit 1

# GNU Make likes to know which target names are not really files to be made:
.PHONY: all install install-lib install-headers clean distclean test check


jcapimin.$(O): jcapimin.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcapistd.$(O): jcapistd.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jccoefct.$(O): jccoefct.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jccolor.$(O): jccolor.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcdctmgr.$(O): jcdctmgr.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jchuff.$(O): jchuff.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jchuff.h
jcinit.$(O): jcinit.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcmainct.$(O): jcmainct.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcmarker.$(O): jcmarker.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcmaster.$(O): jcmaster.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcomapi.$(O): jcomapi.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcparam.$(O): jcparam.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcphuff.$(O): jcphuff.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jchuff.h
jcprepct.$(O): jcprepct.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jcsample.$(O): jcsample.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jctrans.$(O): jctrans.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdapimin.$(O): jdapimin.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdapistd.$(O): jdapistd.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdatadst.$(O): jdatadst.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h
jdatasrc.$(O): jdatasrc.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h
jdcoefct.$(O): jdcoefct.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdcolor.$(O): jdcolor.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jddctmgr.$(O): jddctmgr.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jdhuff.$(O): jdhuff.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdhuff.h
jdinput.$(O): jdinput.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdmainct.$(O): jdmainct.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdmarker.$(O): jdmarker.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdmaster.$(O): jdmaster.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdmerge.$(O): jdmerge.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdphuff.$(O): jdphuff.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdhuff.h
jdpostct.$(O): jdpostct.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdsample.$(O): jdsample.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jdtrans.$(O): jdtrans.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jerror.$(O): jerror.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jversion.h jerror.h
jfdctflt.$(O): jfdctflt.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jfdctfst.$(O): jfdctfst.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jfdctint.$(O): jfdctint.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jidctflt.$(O): jidctflt.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jidctfst.$(O): jidctfst.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jidctint.$(O): jidctint.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jidctred.$(O): jidctred.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jdct.h
jquant1.$(O): jquant1.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jquant2.$(O): jquant2.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jutils.$(O): jutils.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h
jmemmgr.$(O): jmemmgr.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jmemsys.h
jmemansi.$(O): jmemansi.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jmemsys.h
jmemname.$(O): jmemname.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jmemsys.h
jmemnobs.$(O): jmemnobs.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jmemsys.h
jmemdos.$(O): jmemdos.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jmemsys.h
jmemmac.$(O): jmemmac.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h jmemsys.h
cjpeg.$(O): cjpeg.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h jversion.h
djpeg.$(O): djpeg.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h jversion.h
jpegtran.$(O): jpegtran.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h transupp.h jversion.h
rdjpgcom.$(O): rdjpgcom.c jinclude.h jconfig.h
wrjpgcom.$(O): wrjpgcom.c jinclude.h jconfig.h
cdjpeg.$(O): cdjpeg.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
rdcolmap.$(O): rdcolmap.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
rdswitch.$(O): rdswitch.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
transupp.$(O): transupp.c jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jpegint.h jerror.h transupp.h
rdppm.$(O): rdppm.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
wrppm.$(O): wrppm.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
rdgif.$(O): rdgif.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
wrgif.$(O): wrgif.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
rdtarga.$(O): rdtarga.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
wrtarga.$(O): wrtarga.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
rdbmp.$(O): rdbmp.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
wrbmp.$(O): wrbmp.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
rdrle.$(O): rdrle.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
wrrle.$(O): wrrle.c cdjpeg.h jinclude.h jconfig.h jpeglib.h jmorecfg.h jerror.h cderror.h
```

I also tried with --disable-shared in the configure file. Why is the path of --mode=install /usr/bin/install and not the static one. Any idea what are the causes of the installation failure?

Comment: `cannot create regular file 'path_to_libs/libs/jpeg-6b/bin/cjpeg': No such file or directory`

Comment: But shouldn't /bin be generated by the makefile? I configured the ./configure file to install the lib statically. Are the .la files generated also for static libraries? l

Comment: I don't know what is in the makefile to tell if it should create `bin` or not. `path_to_libs` doesn't look like a real path, though. It looks more like a variable name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!. With path_to_libs I mean /home/$USER/Desktop/KIS/libs/jpeg-6b. I run the commands ./configure, make and make install from the jpeg-6b folder which exists for sure. I will attach now the generated makefile. I would appreciate a lot your further help!

Comment: I con't help much more because I don't know how `libtool` works. Although, from what I've read I infer that `.../libs/jpeg-6b/bin/cjpeg` is an input to `./libtool --mode=install ...` and it should be created in some earlier step. Check if directory exists and contain the necessary files. If not something is probably wrong with some earlier step.

Comment: What OS are you installing this on? The script doesn't seem to like your host.

Comment: Hello , I use Ubuntu 19.4